# Looping columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm amazed, maybe someone can explain what's happening....

When I run this very simple example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
results = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for i, col in enumerate(df):
   print('.....'+col)
   result = [print(col) for i in range(2)]
```

The result is (col is unknown the 1st time):

```
.....A
A
A
.....B
A
A
.....C
A
A
```

But what I really expected is:

```
.....A
A
A
.....B
B
B
.....C
C
C
```

What is happening??

Comment: I test it and get expected output in pandas 0.23.0

Comment: The short answer is don't user `print` in a list comprehension. See marked duplicate for more details.

Comment: Works as expected for me

Comment: @jpp I disagree with the duplicate. This is probably an issue related to Python 2's list comprehensions leaking variables.

Comment: @user2285236, Yet the post is marked `[python-3.x]`.. Nevertheless, feel free to reopen if you feel this behaviour deserves an explanation.

Comment: @jpp How does printing inside a comprehension explain `col` variable having the same value all the time?

Comment: @user2285236, I added a few dups for `[python-2.x]` variable leaking. If you think you can add more value, feel free to reopen.

Comment: @jpp I wasn't able to reproduce this it might have been an incorrect guess. I don't see any point in reopening just to vote to close it with another reason so it is best to wait for the op to explain I guess. Thanks.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with my IDE, PyCharm..... If I run it in the console it works, but not in PyCharms. Thank you                                                        `code` Python 3.6.1 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (May 11 2017, 13:09:58) 
   import pandas as pd
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
    results = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
    for i, col in enumerate(df):
       print('.....'+col)
       result = [print(col) for i in range(2)] 
   
.....A
Traceback (most recent call last):
NameError: name 'col' is not defined`code`

Answer (score 0):

I just ran:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['A','B','C'])
results = pd.DataFrame(columns=df.columns)
for i, col in enumerate(df):
   print('.....'+col)
   result = [print(col) for i in range(2)]
```

and it returned:

```
Out[]:
..A
A
A
..B
B
B
..C
C
C
```

Python 3.6.5 
Pandas 0.20.3

Comment: It seems to be a problem with my IDE, PyCharm..... If I run it in the console it works, but not in PyCharms. Thank you